# How is this navigation made possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, responsive-design

I have a quite clear idea in mind for the underlying flow / features for a webpage (module) I'd love to build!

[Example here!:](https://tractatus.xyz/)

I really like this way of navigating, using left / right arrow keys between columns. And the branching structure of the "cards".

I've been learning more Web development as of late, but I thought to seek some guidance before I step full on into it. I'm mostly familiar with [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)) and have briefly touched [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library))... But I'm open to learning pretty much anything. How should I go about approaching making, i.e., a blog with this form of navigation and topical-branching? Any pointers, to tools, similar solutions, could be anything, would be greatly appreciated:)

I’ve tried picking the website above apart, but it didn’t take me far. I am having a real hard time finding out what the correct search terms are, so now I'm mostly just broadly scanning the field of different web applications trying to find if there are better ways to describe what I’m thinking about.

Comment: 1. Listen for key presses 2. Change your state accordingly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just use rxjs operator `fromEvent`

```
export const LEFT_ARROW = 37;
export const UP_ARROW = 38;
export const RIGHT_ARROW = 39;
export const DOWN_ARROW = 40;

finished: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
ngOnInit()
{
   fromEvent(document,'keydown').pipe(
      takeUntil(this.finished)
      filter((key:any)=>key.keyCode>=LEFT_ARROW && key.keyCode<=DOWN_ARROW)
   ).subscribe((key:any)=>{
       switch(key.keyCode)
       {
          case LEFT_ARROW:
             ...
             break;
          case RIGHT_ARROW :
             ...
             break;
          ...
       }
   })
}
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.finished.next();
   this.finished.complete();
}
```